# Create Jar from Checker Framework enabled build?

Tags: java, gradle, checker-framework

I'm adding Checker Framework to an existing Java Gradle build. I have Checker integrated and raising issues and that's all working great. But now that I've added it, my build is no longer producing a .jar file as it once did.

Previously, I'd get a .jar at `build/libs/myproject.jar`. Now instead I see `build/checkerframework` and `build/main` but no `build/libs` and no .jar.

My `build.gradle` is below. Anyone attempted this before? Any success?

I guess I'd also accept an answer that shows how run Checker outside of the build, e.g. `gradle check` to run a build with Checker, and `gradle build` to produce a .jar. But I'd really prefer to have just a single build step if at all possible.

Thanks!

```
plugins {
    id "org.checkerframework" version "0.5.18"
    id 'application'
}

apply plugin: 'org.checkerframework'

checkerFramework {
    checkers = [
        'org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.NullnessChecker',
        'org.checkerframework.checker.units.UnitsChecker'
    ]
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

jar {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

    // Embed all dependencies to create a "fat jar" as required for AWS deployment.
    // Exclude 3rd-party signing files to prevent security errors at runtime
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    } {
        exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF', 'META-INF/*.DSA'
    }

    manifest {
        attributes('Main-Class': 'client.CliMain')
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the build passing?  You said the Checker Framework is "raising issues".  If javac fails, then Gradle won't build the jar files.

Comment: (bangs head on desk)

If you'll post that as an answer I'll accept it. You are right, I was viewing the Checker-raised issues as warnings (because I'm used to using SonarLint, where they are) and totally missed the fact that they were causing the build to error out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the build is passing, then adding `-processor` should not affect whether a `.jar` file is produced.  (Unless you pass `-proc:only` or the like.)

If the build is failing, then Gradle won't build the jar files.
You said the Checker Framework is "raising issues", so maybe the build is failing.